# Explore the convergence series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(k!+1)!}{((k+1)!)!} $$
Since there are factorials I think I should use ratio test but I don't understand how to work with second factorial

Comment: stirling ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem. Explore the convergence series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty{(k! + 1)! \over [(1 + k)!]!}$

For every $k\ge 2$, $(1+k)! = k! + k\cdot k! \ge k! + 2 > k! + 1$.
So,
$${(1 + k!)! \over [(1 + k)!]!} \le {(1 + k!)! \over (2 + k!)!} \le {1 \over k! + 2}\le {1 \over k!}.$$
Since the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty{1 \over k!}$ converges, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty{(k! + 1)! \over [(1 + k)!]!}$ converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the inequalities

$$
\left( {\frac{k}
{3}} \right)^k  \leqslant k! \leqslant 3k\left( {\frac{k}
{2}} \right)^k 
$$
which are true for every $k \geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

well, you have 
$$ ((k+1)!)! = (k+1)k!...((k+1)k!- k!)...(k!+1)!$$
so you have at the very least $((k+1)!)! > (k!+1)!(k!)^{k!}$

from here it's easy